# How to call a method with parameter from a diffrent class

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

Possible noob question but I cant get my method with parameters in one class to call in the other ?

FirstClass

```
public class Firstclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test = new Test1();
        test.Passingvalue();
        test.myMethod();

    }
}
```

SecondClass

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {

    public void Passingvalue (){
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("File Name ? ");
        String txtFile = Scan.next();
    }

    public void myMethod(String txtFile){

        System.out.print("Scan this file" + txtFile);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not sending any parameters to `test.myMethod`. How is it supposed to work then, magic maybe?

Comment: Thats what i am trying to ask how to do

Comment: You could check the parameter you're sending to `System.out.println(...)` as example.

Comment: Yer i know the paramter is ok but on the test.myMethod i get an error because i guess you need something between the brackets but i dont know what is needed between the brackets because if i but the name of the paramter from the method it gets an error

Comment: *i get an error because i guess you need something between the brackets but i dont know what is needed between the brackets* the method states in its signature: `String txtFile`, so it needs a `String` as parameter. You can create a literal `String` by using `"look! this is a String! Yay!"` or by assign a literal `String` to a `String` variable e.g. `String foo = "this is foo";`, then pass this `String` (literal or stored from a variable) to your method.

Comment: And again, take as example `System.out.println`. `System.out` is an object from another class, and provides a method called `println` which receives a `String` as parameter. How do you pass parameters to `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception here:

```
public void Passingvalue (){
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("File Name ? ");
    String txtFile = Scan.next(); //method scope only
}
```

Here the local variable `txtFile` only exists until the method `Passingvalue` (check naming conventions btw) is finished, i.e. it has method scope. Thus when calling `myMethod(String txtFile)` the parameter has the same name but is a different reference in a different scope.

So you'd either have to pass the file name to your method as the others already suggested or change the scope of `txtFile`, e.g. make it an instance variable:

```
public class Test1 {
  private String txtFile; //the scope of this variable is the instance, i.e. it exists as long as the instance of Test1 exists.

  public void Passingvalue (){
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("File Name ? ");
    txtFile = Scan.next();
  }

  public void myMethod(){
    System.out.print("Scan this file" + txtFile);
  }
}
```

Please note that this is just meant to illustrate the immediate problem. There are other issues, e.g. with the general design, which are not addressed. The purpose of your code seems to be learning anyways, so design is not that big an issue for now.

Just as a hint: I'd probably pass the name from outside the method or pass/read it in a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the parameters as a comma separated list in the brackets after the method's name:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 test = new Test1();

    test.myMethod("my_file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add a parameter like this :

```
test.myMethod("txtFile");
```

Answer (score 1):

declare your string txtfile as a public static variable outside the two methods (at the beginning of class test1) .

```
public class Firstclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 test = new Test1();
    test.Passingvalue();
    test.myMethod();

}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {

```
String txtFile;

public void Passingvalue (){
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("File Name ? ");
    txtFile = Scan.next();
}

public void myMethod(){

    System.out.print("Scan this file" + txtFile);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling a parameterize method you should have to pass a parameter to calling method other wise jvm will not understand to whom method you are calling becuase on the basis of parameters we can over load the methods .

so the final answer of your question is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 test = new Test1();

    test.myMethod("place your file name here");
}
```

Comment: Ok i think i understand , you just cant do the way i was trying